# PyQt5, How could i import a PDF file report into a python project

Tags: python, pdf, pyqt5

In order to develop a lesson project i should import a PDF file to a python project. PDF is 9 pages (is the theoretical report of project). Any idea for how could i solve this?

Comment: pdfrw, poppler-qt5, and pdfminer look promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you "import" a PDF file into a python project depends on what you plan on doing with it. Python has several modules that allow you to open/parse/read a PDF file, including poppler, pdfrw, pdfminer. However if you want to display the said PDf file using PyQt5, then you should concentrate on Poppler's PyQt bindings. [This link](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167) might help you.